# Getting element's height with jQuery in IE11

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, internet-explorer

I have a submit input button with these styles:

```
display: block;
width; 200px;
box-sizing: border-box;
margin: 0;
padding-top: 16px;
padding-right: 32px;
padding-bottom: 16px;
padding-left: 32px;
font-size: 16px;
float: right;
height: 55px;
```

I use this element's height property in my jQuery code with `.css('height')` (returns `'55px'`) and it works well in FF and Chrome… but when it comes to goddamn IE, it returns 78px, which is 55px (full element's height including padding) + 23px (element's height - padding), which is how I think it gets it. I tried using `height()`, `innerHeight()`, and `outerHeight()` but none return the correct height in IE.

How do I get the correct height of an element on IE?

Comment: have you tried clientHeight

Comment: have you tried with $(..).height() on IE? I mean does help if you access the value that way. on jQuery it say: "The .height() method is recommended when an element's height needs to be used in a mathematical calculation."  http://api.jquery.com/height/

Comment: Can you post the complete code? or what you tried?

Comment: clientHeight seems to be vanilla javascript method, but I use jQuery. As I pointed out in the question, I used height(), innerHeight(), outerHeight() and none of those were consistent across the browsers.

Comment: Is using jQuery is an imperative in your case?

Comment: it's preferably, I can't believe such a simple task cant be done with any simple way

Comment: I understand your point. But just to make it simple, I would add height in style property like <input type="button" id="btn" style="height: 155px;" /> and then call it with document.getElementById("btn").style.height

Comment: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/ktzo5f8x/1/) shows inner height same in all the browsers

Comment: Isn't your document mode "Quirks" in IE? That has a completely broken box model.

Comment: No, mode is "standart". I managed to figure out that it gets wrong height value only if the button's placed in a hidden modal, so that somehow affects it in IE, but not in chrome or FF. I found a way to get a correct value with cloning the button, giving it absolute position, putting it outside the screen and then getting its height with css('height') but I still dont understand why it cant get a css height value of an element that parent's hidden?

Comment: I think that's the reason http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/14922

Comment: it is a case of the element being hidden...  sucks ass really...  works with chrome and firefox...  explorer 11, and edge fail...  in my case I just got the element height before hiding the element...  might not be a solution for you, but it's a quirk of the browser